# Return Status of DAG-A in another DAG-B

Tags: python, airflow, pipeline

I am looking for a way to retrieve the last status of  DAG-A, in a another DAG-B. Then pass that status as a string in my current DAG-B.

But I cannot find anything online? I don't want to check the status of DAG-A.

Say DAG-A triggers multiple times a day, whenever DAG-B triggers (custom time) I want it to have the last status of DAG-A.

I just have code that would output a Slack Message, having a Slack Message in DAG-A is unfortunately not a good solution for my problem. And I would like to learn how to return status of others dags.

I would want to pass the status in the message body.

```
def _get_message() -> str:
    return "Status of data_pipeline: "

with DAG("slack_dag", start_date=datetime(2021, 1 ,1), 
    schedule_interval="@daily", default_args=default_args, catchup=False
    ) as dag:


    send_slack_notification = SlackWebhookOperator (
        task_id="send_slack_notification",
        http_conn_id="slack_conn",
        message=_get_message(),
        channel="#test-public"
    )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the `airflow.models.DagRun` object you can query DagRuns occurring between an `execution_start_date` and `execution_end_date`. Below is code for `dag_b` which contains task `get_dagrun_info` that queries all runs for `dag_a` in the last 10 minutes and logs the latest dagrun state.

Here is the key snippet:

```py
from airflow.models import DagRun


@task
def get_dagrun_info():
    dag_runs = DagRun.find(
        dag_id="dag_a",
        execution_start_date=(datetime.now(timezone.utc)-timedelta(600)),
        execution_end_date=datetime.now(timezone.utc)
    )
    latest_run = dag_runs[-1]
    logging.info(latest_run)
    logging.info(f"state of latest run for {latest_run.dag_id} is {latest_run.state}")
```

Here is the full DAG code

```py
import logging
from datetime import datetime, timezone, timedelta

from airflow.decorators import dag, task
from airflow.models import DagRun


@task
def get_dagrun_info():
    dag_runs = DagRun.find(
        dag_id="dag_a",
        execution_start_date=(datetime.now(timezone.utc)-timedelta(600)),
        execution_end_date=datetime.now(timezone.utc)
    )
    latest_run = dag_runs[-1]
    logging.info(latest_run)
    logging.info(f"state of latest run for {latest_run.dag_id} is {latest_run.state}")


@dag(
    dag_id="dag_b",
    schedule=None,
    start_date=datetime(2023, 8, 15),
    catchup=False
)
def my_dag():
    return get_dagrun_info()

my_dag()
```

Comment: Thanks for this it has been really helpful. Do you have any best ideas regarding implementing this for multiple DAG's? Thinking of creating a list then looping this function through the list. So I can get the status per each DAG in one message/variable.

Comment: Use a json file to organize all the information and iterate through a loop to generate the DAGs.